# GET and SET CSRF Token in AJAX request

Tags: ajax, angularjs, laravel-5, csrf-protection

I am sending some data to my server via **$AJAX**, now i keep getting the

> Token Mismatch Exception Error

.

When i use **$http** i do not get this error so i do not understand what makes **$AJAX** soo different.  I have checked online for solutions but all the solutions involved doing something like this:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Thing is i do not use blade, my client code is completely independent of any server code so using methods like that is not an option, plus i also had a situation in the past where i had to refresh my application after making a post before i could make another post using that method, i dunno why.

What i am basically asking is how to **GET** CSRF Token from the server using only javascript and **SET** it in my header in my AJAX request without any server code.

I am using **Jquery AJAX** for this **NOT** the **$http** service in AngularJS

The **GET** part is the main issue here.

Comment: what ajax request. ...if you aren't using `$http` what are you using? Or is this written incorrectly because it says you have no problem when using `$http`?

Comment: I am using Jquery AJAX

Comment: why are you using `$.ajax` when you ask for angular and `$http` already works fine? Did you look at how to set headers in the `$.ajax` docs?

Comment: I am using a directive that uses $.ajax, in my main application i use $.http, i cannot change this, it was written by somebody else.

Comment: well there are numerous ways to set the headers all explained in jQuery docs. If you don't want to change the `$.ajax` code use a global method.. start by reading the manual

Comment: I know how to set the headers in $.ajax, my question is how to GET the CSRF token from the server and SET it in $.ajax request.  Basically the GETting part is the main issue here.

Comment: Please read the last part of my post very well i don't think you understand me.

Comment: Was hard to understand because problem description in question is terrible. By default `$http` reads it from cookie....this is explained in `$http` docs. Look at your cookies

Comment: Yes i am aware $http reads it from the cookie by default, however $.ajax appears not to, that is why i am asking HOW to do it.

Comment: read the cookie and set the headers from it

Comment: @user3718908, does this help you? https://gist.github.com/alanhamlett/6316427 You need to use fiddler to see what is the cookie name which is being set.

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa principles of beforeSend in gist are good...note however that `$.ajaxSetup` docs state to no longer use that method `we strongly recommend against using this API`

Comment: @Erti-Chris Eelmaa I just tried it, it did't work, so i changed the name of the cookie to match what was in the docs and that still did not work, is there an alternative way?

Comment: @user3718908 use that cookie getter function by itself ...even in console to see what it returns. `doesn't work` isn't much of a description...inspect the sent headers too. Also note my comment above about not using `$,ajxSetup` per jQuery docs

Comment: Okay so if it is strongly recommended that we do not use that API then what is the alternative?